# "Checkout is not available while your cart is empty" problem

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was doing the woo-commerce website and doing testing. I add the product to the cart and proceed to checkout. I was then select to pay with blizpay and it directs me to the blizpay payment page. I was then manually clicked back to return to the woo-commerce website to cancel the payment and it shows Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty. My previous added product was gone. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You previous add products are not in cart. It goes to order log and payment status of those products are pending.

[image]

Comment: so how should i fix with this problem?

Comment: it's default functionality of woocommerce, if you click on cancel button during payment, it means that user couldn't pay and order goes to pending payment